# Having an empty xs:date element being validated OK by the XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this in my XSD:

```
<xs:element name="End_Date" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
```

I would like the validation pass if there's a date or if there's an empty node

`<End_Date>2011-05-31T00:00:00.000</End_Date>`
should be ok as well as 
`<End_Date></End_Date>`

How can I modifiy the XSD to make it so?

I tried different things:

`nillable="true"`

and

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"
```

and

```
                    <xs:element name="End_Date">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:date">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:union>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
```

None of them worked.

Error:

> Error detected : The 'xxxxxxxxxx:End_Date' element is invalid - The
>   value '' is invalid according to its datatype
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:date' - The string '' is not a valid
>   XsdDateTime value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are confused about the difference between xs:date and xs:dateTime. You have used xs:date in your schema, but your example is an xs:dateTime.

There are three ways of achieving what you want:

(a) define a type that is a union of (xs:dateTime and (restriction of xs:string allowing only ""))

(b) define a type that is a list of xs:dateTime with minLength = 0, maxLength = 1

(c) define the element to be nillable. In this case the instance will have to say xsi:nil="true", which to my mind makes the facility pretty useless.

If you try one of these and it doesn't work, tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Type="xs:date", derivedBy="list" and minOccurs="0"

which looks like this in your XML Schem Document 

<xs:element name="EffectiveDt" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:list itemType="xs:date"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

This will surely help you, I tried in my Code Works perfect.
```

[Validate Your XML against XSD here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html)

```
I am using this online XML validation against XSD tool.
```

Comment: The only problem I have found with this strategy is that you allow for supplying a list of elements like ...<EffectiveDt/><EffectiveDt/><EffectiveDt/><EffectiveDt/>...

Comment: @MartinSjöblom No, this schema does not allow a list of elements, it only allows a list of dates within a single element.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

[in xsd :]

```
<xs:simpleType name="DateOrEmptyDate">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:date">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value=""/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

[Valid xml :]

```
<EndDate/>
<EndDate>2017-12-31</EndDate>
```

[Invalid xml :]

`<EndDate>2017-31-31</EndDate>`

Comment: I think it would help show a greater deal of understanding and avoid back and forth questions if you explained what about your approach differs to that of the OP and why your approach works.

Comment: Hmmm. God bless working examples ;-) but it seems that "xsd:union" can be useful to customize unsatisfying xsd rules

Answer (score 0):

xsi:nill=true should definitely be valid as long as you define the schema element as nillable. What validator are you using?

Schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://myNS" targetNamespace="http://myNS" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="End_Date" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Instance:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="myNS">
  <End_Date xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</ns0:Root>
```

is valid.

Comment: I'm using .NET for the validation. What do you  mean by instance? I have one XSD. I tried adding nillable="true" in my xs:element and I get the same error message.

Comment: I assume you are trying to validate an xml against the xsd? The "instance" in my answer is the xml to validate. So in the xsd you define a nillable type called End_Date with the nillable attribute = true. Then in the xml document when you author the End_Date element you can use the xsi:nil="true" attribute. As I said before this will definitely validate.

Comment: Still no go : ( In my XML to validate I put: `<End_Date xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"></End_Date>` In the XSD I put: `<xs:element name="End_Date" type="xs:date" nillable="true" />` I get the error:  `The 'http://cdcixis-cm.com/gbo:End_Date' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:date' - The string '' is not a valid XsdDateTime value.`

Comment: Are you sure that is the only End_Date type in your xsd schema tree?

Comment: No worries. still cannot understand why you could not get that to validate.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant but I had exactly this problem when attempting to deserialize. My problems was that my target property was not nullable: public DateTime? theData ...